# Navlink causes URL to change but page does not load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router, react-router-dom

I've built an app with a few pages. There is a navigation bar with different Links related to authentication("Login", "Signup" etc). The pages change the URL and they load the appropriate content when I type into the URL but when I click on a `NavLink` with the same URL, the URL changes but the page doesn't load. It's almost as though it goes into a loop because I have to stop the local server and close the tab to stop the process.

I've been struggling with this since morning and I thought it was because I didn't have a `useEffect` cleanup, compatibility issues with `react-router` 6 and `react` 18 etc. I think its a `react-router` issue but I can't put my finger on it.

In case it matters:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.6.2"
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import LogIn from "./pages/LogIn";

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation />
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navigation.jsx

```
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { signOut, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Navigation() {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState();

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onLogOut = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        toast.success("You are signed out");
        console.log("You are signed out");
        navigate("/login");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error("Something went wrong");
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul className="flex p-2 place-content-evenly">
        <li>BraThula</li>
        {!isLoggedIn && <NavLink to="login">Login</NavLink>}
        {!isLoggedIn && <NavLink to="signup">Signup</NavLink>}
        {isLoggedIn && (
          <li className="cursor-pointer" onClick={onLogOut}>
            logout
          </li>
        )}
        {isLoggedIn && <li className="">Hello, {user.name}</li>}
        {isLoggedIn && <li className="">Current User: {user.email}</li>}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `onAuthStateChanged` function is being unconditionally called as an unintentional side-effect and enqueues a state update which triggers a rerender. This creates a render loop.

Move the `onAuthStateChanged` logic into a `React.useEffect` hook so it's called only once when the component mounts. Don't forget to return a cleanup function to unsubscribe from the auth changes.

Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    setIsLoggedIn(!!user);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```